# Convertendo boolean para SIM ou NÃO em AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabela no meu formulário `HTML`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr nr-repeat="p in model.previdencias">
        <td>{{p.NomeDependente}}</td>
        <td>{{p.IsAtivo}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

O atributo `p.IsAtivo` é do tipo `boolean` que retorna `true` ou `false`. Gostaria de fazer um `ifinline` para para escrever Sim ou Não na coluna da table conforme o valor do campo.
Fiz da seguinte maneira, mas não deu certo:

```
<td>{{p.IsAtivo ? 'Sim' : 'Não'}}</td>
```

Como devo fazer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei o seguinte link :[angularjs-print-yes-or-no-based-on-boolean-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380406/angularjs-print-yes-or-no-based-on-boolean-value) e resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
<td>{{true == p.IsAtivo ? 'Sim' : 'Não' }}</td>
```